# How to convert a double to a char[] and back for reading / writing to binary file?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, ieee-754

I'm trying to write a double to a binary file, but can't figure out how to convert it to a char[] in a portable way. I'd like to write it in the [IEEE double precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), big endian, and convert it back to the current platform's format.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As the representation of float is not defined by the standard **in general** and left to the implementaion, there is _no_ portable way. However, if your implementation uses IEEE754 floating point (`__STDC_IEC_559__` defined), you can at least avoid bit-twiddling.

Comment: Do you need portable code or code for some particular platform?

Comment: Portable code... I guess. By that I mean I don't have any existing implementation that only works on a specific platform.

Comment: @Olaf what do you mean by "you can at least avoid bit-twiddling"?

Comment: COnverting the implementation's representation to/from ISO format?

Comment: @JackMaloney Then you need a portable IEEE double precision float library. Use a search engine.

Comment: @JackMaloney: In general, a binary format is a bad idea for portable data-interchange (and for debugging, btw.). There are good reasons JSON and XML have become widely accepted now, even in the Windows-world of proprietary binary formats.

Comment: Yeah, except I'm using this for an interpreter, and I want a binary format for it's speed. I could always just write the float as a string and read it in using `strtod` or something, and use binary for everything else. Preferably I'd like to have the whole thing in binary though.

Comment: @Pynchia: There is no advantage in either endianess, as the data has to be read into a variable anyway.

Comment: @Pynchia the problem isn't the file format, it's the conversion between the platform's format and the file format.

Comment: @JackMaloney: An interpreter would use text actually. Otherwise you can first convert internally to bytecode. Sounds as if you are re-inventing the wheel for the 1000thed.

Comment: @Olaf it's a bytecode interpreter. I would like the bytecode format to be binary because its fast. I also have a text version of the bytecode that is compiled/assembled into the binary format. I'm not sure what the problem with that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various approaches:

1) Use a string.  If `FLT_RADIX` is 10, use `fprintf(outf, " %.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, x)`, otherwise use `fprintf(outf, " %a", x)` ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840224/2410359)).  Use `fscanf(inf, "%lf", &x)` to read back. (`"%la"` has same effect)

2) Use a union and assume `double` format is [IEEE double precision binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), maybe also use defined [endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637447/how-can-i-convert-little-endian-to-big-endian-using-htonl) and *nix: `htonl()`

```
union d2a {
  double d;
  unsigned char uc[sizeof double];
} u;

u.d = x;
ToNetworkEndian(u.uc);
fwrite(u.uc, 1, sizeof u.uc, outf);

fread(u.uc, 1, sizeof u.uc, inf);
FromNetworkEndian(u.uc);
x = u.d;
```

3) Write a lot of code to covert compiler's non-standard `double` to `IEEE` taking into account: different precision, range, [wobbling precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture), +/- 0, [sub-normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), etc.

Recommend option 1

Answer (score -3):

C and C++ have an fread and fwrite, which just copy the bytes from your specified location in a specified chunk size to a specified file stream and vice versa... You wouldn't have to convert to a char[]

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is endianness... Unless I'm mistaken about how this would work.

Comment: You're not mistaken. Here's how I'd go about it... Regardless of platform, whenever you write to file, just use fwrite. You'll copy the bytes in linear order into a binary file. Whenever you read, write a wrapper function that flips your byte order.

Comment: @DushyantSrikant  Not good enough.  Two different platforms could write the float to disk in two different formats.  To be portable, what gets written to disk (or alternately, sent over a network) has to be in a known format.

Comment: @JackMaloney: No, the problem is also alignment and the implementation's representation of floating point values. The standard does **not** enforce a specific representation. It just details how a ISO compliant version has to behave. And even with that, there might be padding. E.g. MSVC and gcc us different `sizeof` for `long double`, but the same FPU (i.e. the same bit-representation). THe difference is just padding.

Comment: @Olaf How would one go about converting non-ISO floats to the ISO format?

Comment: @JackMaloney: Well, you asked about a portable way. That includes systems with non-ISO floating points. If not, you should restrict your question to internal ISO representation, still leaving alignment/padding issues.

Comment: @Olaf So what you're saying is that there is no portable way to do this? And what would the alignment/padding issues be?

Comment: @JackMaloney: Please think about the implications of "**implementation defined**" with regard of portability, aka "**not implementation dependent**". Just read the standard, you might start [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6), but read further.